# Отличие в скорости работы

Tags: c++

Написал вот дакой код. Если вместо `vector<char>` выбрать тип `vector<int>`, то скорость выполнения программы увеличивается раза в 2. В чём может быть причина?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (auto i = 1; i <= 500000000; i++) {
        v.push_back(i);
        if (i % 100000000 == 0) {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: эти типы занимают разный объем памяти. И размер вектора в случае int будет около 2 гигабайт. А char - 0.5 гигабайта. А это существенно. То есть, код тестирует скорость выделения большого кол-ва памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim только, кажется, int занимает 2 байта (или 4 байта), а char -- 1, нет? Кажется, зависимость должна быть ровно обратная. `vector<char>` должен шустрее работать.

Comment: А главное, у вас `i` будет обрезаться до `char`'a, и в векторе будут неверные данные.

Comment: @Harry ок, спасибо. Это ща не важно. Мне интересно, почему скорость отличается

Comment: Потому что выделение памяти отличается в 4 раза. А если вы уберете вывод на экран - разница увеличится еще больше, у меня - в 3 раза. А если добавить `v.reserve(500000000);` - то разница станет минимальной...

Comment: @Harry Ну так, правильно, на `char` тратиться меньше ресурсов: т.е. выделяется 1 байт. На `int` тратится больше ресурсов, так как выделяется 4 байта. Тогда почему вектор с `char`, работает медленнее, если ресурсов тратится больше?

Comment: Почему медленнее?... Вот: https://ideone.com/niGp12 - правда, пришлось урезать размер, иначе ограничение по времени срывало выполнение. Вот если бы вы дальше всерьез работали с этим вектором - то да, обращение к `int` из-за выравнивания оказалось бы более быстрым, чем к `char`.

Comment: @user7860670 и?

Comment: @Harry потому что у меня именно это и наблюдается. Обратное тому, что Вы привели в примере

Comment: @user7860670 Вы думаете я просто так задал вопрос? Я всё верно написал. И именно поэтому спрашиваю.

Comment: @hedgehogues В вопросе вы говорите, что с `char` быстрее, в комментарии - что медленнее... Вы уж выберите что-то одно, а?...

Comment: @Harry поправил вопрос

Comment: Не наблюдаю. В вашем варианте *с выводом* у меня соотношение времени 3.71 секунды для int и 3.76 для char - разница в пределах погрешности, потому что основная работа в вашем варианте - **не** с вектором.

Comment: @hedgehogues Вам еще стоит привести используемый компилятор и параметры сборки. Чтобы заявленное поведение могли воспроизвести читающие вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все не так как кажется на первый взгляд. То, что для программиста выглядит очень похожим, на самом деле в коде может быть совершенно разным. Совершенно.

Давайте посмотрим на внутренний цикл с точки зрения gcc с -O0.

c int

```
.L5:
        cmp     DWORD PTR -52[rbp], 500000000
        jg      .L4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR -52[rbp]
        mov     BYTE PTR -53[rbp], al
        lea     rdx, -53[rbp]
        lea     rax, -48[rbp]
        mov     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::push_back(char&&)
        add     DWORD PTR -52[rbp], 1
        jmp     .L5
.L4:
```

char

```
.L5:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR -52[rbp]
        cmp     eax, 500000000
        jg      .L4
        lea     rdx, -52[rbp]
        lea     rax, -48[rbp]
        mov     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&)
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR -52[rbp]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR -52[rbp], eax
        jmp     .L5
.L4:
```

Компилятор как минимум сделал больше кода. К примеру, в случае с int он просто инкрементит переменную по адресу в памяти. В случае с char - вычитывает с памяти в регистр, увеличивает и пишет назад. То же самое и с сравнением. А чтение-запись памяти дешево не дается. Это объясняет, почему вариант с char медленее. Добавим `-O1` и картина сильно меняется. В моих тестах char быстрее где то в 2.5 раза. Но и общее время сильно-сильно улучшилось

Я сделал такое же и для clang. Результат не сильно отличается. Правда clang сделал более компактный код. Сравним.

для int

```
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 36], 500000000
        jg      .LBB0_6
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 32]
        lea     rsi, [rbp - 36]
        call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&)
        jmp     .LBB0_3
.LBB0_3:
```

char

```
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 36], 500000000
        jg      .LBB0_6
        mov     al, byte ptr [rbp - 36]
        mov     byte ptr [rbp - 37], al
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 32]
        lea     rsi, [rbp - 37]
        call    std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::push_back(char&&)
        jmp     .LBB0_3
.LBB0_3:
```

Но вот с O1 clang был медленее gcc c O1.  Но тесты для char/int дали приблизительно одинаковые результаты. Но уже на O2 все стало на свои места.

Вывод. Такая разница не в выводе на консоль. пять маленьких строк не сыграют большой роли при 2-3 секундах выполнения.

Компилятор не спроста сделал так. Все дело в разных типах. Компилятор вынужден вставить неявное преобразование int в char. Для этого он копирует только последний байт регистра. А так как регистр eax при этом "портится", то его нужно постоянно куда то сохранять. Вот и весь ответ.

Comment: Что делают флаги O0, O1, O2?

Comment: это флаги gcc/clang для включения оптимизации. O0 - не оптимизировать. O1 - немножко, O2 - все известные классные оптимизации. O3 - рискованные. Для студии ключи похожие - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?view=vs-2019

Comment: Почему бы всегда не использовать по умолчанию O2? Что такое рискованные?

Comment: больше оптимизаций - дольше компиляция, сложнее отлаживать. "рискованные" оптимизации могут "сломать" програму и она перестанет работать так, как нужно. О3 это место, где тестят оптимизации, а потом, когда их отладили и они рабтают хорошо, переносят в О2